# how to get total number of earnings using Thinkscript?

Tags: thinkscript

I want to count the total number of earnings on the chart. if this is 1 year daily chart, I should get 4 earnings back. no error message,but label is not showing on the chart.

```
def earningCount = if IsNaN(earningCount) then 0 else if hasEarnings() then earningCount + 1 else earningCount;
AddLabel(yes, "There are total " + earningCount + " earnings");
```

Comment: You actually get an error message (click on the exclamation mark where your label should be): "EarningsTotal: Trying to self-assign a non-initialized rec: earningCount.". Hope that helps your troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is start with the first day and iterate through each previous day asking hasEarnings(). Unfortunately, without any for/while loop functionality in thinkscript, this will be extremely tedious:

```
def earningCount;

#get latest date
def today = getYYYYMmDd();

#get first date in chart
def firstDay = first(today);

#get number of days to iterate through:
def numOfDays = CountTradingDays(firstDay,today);

#Ask for each day one at a time: if hasEarnings() then earningCount + 1 else Double.NaN;

#today
today

#day before
today[1]

#day before that... etc..
today[2]

#... until first day in chart
today[numOfDays]
```

Not the optimal solution you would have wanted. Alternatively, you could ask how many years in the chart and multiple by 4 as you know there are usually 4 earnings/yr...

Answer (score 0):

```
def earningCount = if IsNaN(earningCount[1]) then 0 else if hasEarnings() then earningCount[1] + 1 else earningCount[1];
AddLabel(yes, "There are total " + earningCount + " earnings");
```

Comment: Please [edit] the answer and add some explanation as to why one should try out your solution.